# Summary statistic for an error measurement

Tags: experiment-design, descriptive-statistics

I have $n$ error measures that can be positive or negative values. Negative values are more important for my experiment than positive values. Of course, taking the mean of the $n$ values doesn't make sense because the mean could be $0$ and that won't reflect in one number what is happening. What summary statistic can you recommend me for this case?

I would really appreciate any suggestion.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How *much* more important are the negative values?

Comment: They are critical. The positive values are not critical but they give an idea of the general accuracy of the process.

Comment: It might be possible to be more quantitative than "critical."  In another comment you refer to a "planar cutting process."  Does this mean you are cutting material out of a planar sheet according to a pattern?  In such a case a negative error would ruin the cut, which incurs a certain cost, but avoiding negative errors would introduce more waste and use more time cleaning up the cut, which has its attendant cost.  From this point of view, the objective becomes one of minimizing expected cost.  An appropriate summary statistic would reflect the chance of ruining the work.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with the square root of the mean of the squared errors (ie, RMS error), though the mean of the absolute values would not be too different.

The average of the errors would tell you about *bias*, which is also interesting.  If you care more about errors in one direction than the other, than you'd want some bias (toward the direction that is of less concern).

Comment: thanks! What if I want to produce two summary statistics, one for the positive values and one for the negative values, and establish a relationship or a kind of proportion in between them, is that a reasonable approach? Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @Federico - You could take the average of the positive values and the average of the negative values, or the RMS of each of these portions.

Comment: On the contrary, I think this situation demands that there be some bias.  In the extreme case, only the negative values are of concern and positive values are of no concern.  It would then be ideal for all the error measures to be positive.  (Imagine trying to estimate the lower envelope of a scatterplot, for instance.)

Comment: @whuber - Indeed you're right. If you care more about one direction of error than the other, it'd be better to allow bias. It'd be helpful to have some context.

Comment: @whuber - I corrected the point about bias.  (Hopefully I was right to do so.)

Comment: @Karl Broman - I'm measuring a planar cutting process, and the negative and positive error values depend on whether the cutting process at a certain point was on one side or the other of the plane. Actually, the positive values are less important in the process than the negative values. I want to show the overall process performance in a few numbers, so maybe I could use RMS to show the general accuracy, and then the mean of the negative values to show the ones that have more impact for the process.